# Activating Matlab error: License checkout failed. License Manager Error -9

Tags: matlab, installation, license-key

Im on Linux Manjaro.
I tried everything that came to my mind but I'm still getting this error:

```sh
[john@john-pc bin]$ sudo ./matlab
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -9
Your username does not match the username in the license file. 
To run on this computer, you must run the Activation client to reactivate your license.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
https://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2020a/9

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: MATLAB 
License path: /root/.matlab/R2020a_licenses:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/licenses/license.dat:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a
/licenses/license_john-pc_40911196_R2020a.lic 
Licensing error: -9,57.
```

I ran `./activate_matlab.sh` and activated it through the `license` file AND login into MathWorks online. I deleted the installation `.lic` in `R2020a/license/` and created a new one. I tried creating a license file with every mac address I could find. Nothing works. I keep getting this error. Only once I managed to use Matlab, which was right after installing it. Then after the first time closing it I'm I have been stuck on this error for 2 days. Please help me.

Comment: I suggest you contact MathWorks technical support. They will be able to help you.

Comment: @Paolo okay i wrote to them and I got it working! I posted the answer

Comment: Cool, that was quick!

Comment: @Paolo They replied in like 20 minutes, not gonna a surprise to be sure but a welcome one <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I wrote to MathWorks support. And they gave me a link to their forum where I found the solution. Here it is:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99067-why-do-i-receive-license-manager-error-9

I had to go all the way up to copying my HostID etc and set my login as `root` and run Matlab with `sudo`

But in case the link dies here it is from the MathWorks post:
The best way to resolve a License Manager Error -9 is by reactivating MATLAB with the activation client.

`Windows`

The activation client is located here:

`C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R20XXx\bin\winXX\activate_matlab.exe`

`Mac`

- Open Finder.
- Go to "Applications".
- Right-click or control-click on the MATLAB application icon. (e.g. MATLAB_R2015b.app)
- Click on "Show Package Contents".
- Open "Activate.app".

`Linux`

The activation client is located here:

`/usr/local/MATLAB/R20XXx/bin/activate_matlab.sh`

**Once you have launched the MATLAB activation client:**

- Select "Activate automatically using the internet."
- Log into your MathWorks account.
- Select the correct license.
- The username field should auto-populate with the correct user name. Leave it as is.
- Confirm the activation information.
- Click "finish" to complete the activation process.
- Restart MATLAB.

**Still seeing a License Manager Error -9?**

- The username in the license file does not match
- The Host ID in the license file does not match
- You have a Designated Computer MATLAB license and MATLAB is already running under a different user account on this computer.

**Confirm your Username and Host ID using the activation client:**

- Run the activation client and select "Activate manually without using the Internet."
- Choose “I do not have a license file. Help me with the next steps.”
- Copy your Host ID and Computer Login Name.
- Click the back arrow 2 times and choose “Activate automatically using the Internet” then input the appropriate username.
- Launch MATLAB using the appropriate user account.

**Activation client requires elevated privileges to run? Connection error when Activating automatically? Still seeing a License Manager Error – 9?**

How do I activate MATLAB without an internet connection?

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/259627